# How to change pin it button (Pinterest) background rectangle to round?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-activity, android-fragments

I am using pint it button in my application but it is in rectangle shape. How can i change  in round button with custom background. How can i set background of pint it button.

```
 <com.pinterest.pinit.PinItButton
    android:id="@+id/pin_bt"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:layout_margin="5dp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use rounded corner imageview code for xml

```
<in.appera.sachin.ImageViewRounded 
        android:id="@+id/ivProfile"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
         />
```

code for ImageViewRounded .class

```
import android.content.Context
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Bitmap.Config;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.PorterDuff;
import android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode;
import android.graphics.PorterDuffXfermode;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class ImageViewRounded extends ImageView {

public ImageViewRounded(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public ImageViewRounded(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public ImageViewRounded(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) getDrawable();

    if (drawable == null) {
        return;
    }

    if (getWidth() == 0 || getHeight() == 0) {
        return;
    }

    Bitmap fullSizeBitmap = drawable.getBitmap();

    int scaledWidth = getMeasuredWidth();
    int scaledHeight = getMeasuredHeight();

    Bitmap mScaledBitmap;
    if (scaledWidth == fullSizeBitmap.getWidth()
            && scaledHeight == fullSizeBitmap.getHeight()) {
        mScaledBitmap = fullSizeBitmap;
    } else {
        mScaledBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(fullSizeBitmap,
                scaledWidth, scaledHeight, true /* filter */);
    }

    // Bitmap roundBitmap = getRoundedCornerBitmap(mScaledBitmap);

    // Bitmap roundBitmap = getRoundedCornerBitmap(getContext(),
    // mScaledBitmap, 10, scaledWidth, scaledHeight, false, false,
    // false, false);
    // canvas.drawBitmap(roundBitmap, 0, 0, null);

    Bitmap circleBitmap = getCircledBitmap(mScaledBitmap);

    canvas.drawBitmap(circleBitmap, 0, 0, null);

}

public Bitmap getRoundedCornerBitmap(Context context, Bitmap input,
        int pixels, int w, int h, boolean squareTL, boolean squareTR,
        boolean squareBL, boolean squareBR) {

    Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);
    final float densityMultiplier = context.getResources()
            .getDisplayMetrics().density;

    final int color = 0xff424242;

    final Paint paint = new Paint();
    final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, w, h);
    final RectF rectF = new RectF(rect);

    // make sure that our rounded corner is scaled appropriately
    final float roundPx = pixels * densityMultiplier;

    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
    paint.setColor(color);
    canvas.drawRoundRect(rectF, roundPx, roundPx, paint);

    // draw rectangles over the corners we want to be square
    if (squareTL) {
        canvas.drawRect(0, 0, w / 2, h / 2, paint);
    }
    if (squareTR) {
        canvas.drawRect(w / 2, 0, w, h / 2, paint);
    }
    if (squareBL) {
        canvas.drawRect(0, h / 2, w / 2, h, paint);
    }
    if (squareBR) {
        canvas.drawRect(w / 2, h / 2, w, h, paint);
    }

    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));
    canvas.drawBitmap(input, 0, 0, paint);

    return output;
}

Bitmap getCircledBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {

    Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(),
            bitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(result);

    int color = Color.BLUE;
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());

    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
    paint.setColor(color);
    // canvas.drawRoundRect(rectF, roundPx, roundPx, paint);
    canvas.drawCircle(bitmap.getWidth() / 2, bitmap.getHeight() / 2,
            bitmap.getHeight() / 2, paint);

    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rect, paint);

    return result;
}
```